# which NoSQL database is suitable for this rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, wiki

Building a rails application which will be used to edit documents, two persons may edit the same document concurrently but on their own branch, each can't see others' change until they are ready to push and merge it back to the master branch, and until they pull the latest changes from the master into their own branch.

what's the best NoSQL DB or solution for this rails application?

Answer (score 2):

You could do all of this with the filesystem and `git` so I'm not sure why you'd even need a database here except for auxiliary functions. There's nothing in your requirements that would promote one DB over another.

I'd go with whatever you know best. Even a regular SQL DB would have zero trouble handling this.

Comment: Using a DB would let us make use of the MVC framework as much as possible, I'm still not sure how can git be used to replace the DB as as a module in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Are the documents stored as plain text or encoded in a format (such that it needs to be binary in the DB) that requires the server to decoded and perform the merge itself?

The scenario you are describing it some what documented collection oriented in that you're effectively pushing the same type of metadata but potentially with different key/values. You may be interested in something like CouchDB or MongoDB. Both express a document in a JSON (BSON in MongoDB) like fashion, allowing each document to have differing keys.

Comment: The documents may be in plain text, json, xml and binary formats. if the DB can do the merge, it would be ideally.